# How to extract values (list and unique tags) from xml in Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a xml file that contains some tags, one is unique other are same tags. I'd like to get values from these tags and convert them to another xml tag. Here is example of xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry dataset="Swiss-Prot" created="2005-04-26" modified="2019-11-13" version="158" xmlns="http://uniprot.org/uniprot" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<accession>Q96IY4</accession>
<accession>A8K464</accession>
<accession>Q15114</accession>
<accession>Q5T9K1</accession>
<accession>Q5T9K2</accession>
<accession>Q9P2Y6</accession>
<name>CBPB2_HUMAN</name>
<protein>
   <recommendedName>
     <fullName>Carboxypeptidase B2</fullName>
     <ecNumber evidence="7">3.4.17.20</ecNumber>
   </recommendedName>
   <alternativeName>
      <fullName>Carboxypeptidase U</fullName>
      <shortName>CPU</shortName>
   </alternativeName>
   <alternativeName>
      <fullName>Plasma carboxypeptidase B</fullName>
      <shortName>pCPB</shortName>
   </alternativeName>
   <alternativeName>
      <fullName>Thrombin-activable fibrinolysis inhibitor</fullName>
      <shortName>TAFI</shortName>
   </alternativeName>
</protein>...other tags
</entry>
```

I though of using EvaluateXQuery processor and EvaluateXPath. EvaluateXQuery is using for getting accession and alternativeName tags. EvaluateXPath is using for getting name, recommendedName (fullName) tags.

Is it possible to use both and combine them to only xml or hust necessary to use EvaluateXQuery processor, like this:

```
<accessions>Q96IY4, A8K464, Q15114,...</accessions>
<name>CBPB2_HUMAN</name>
<recommendedName>Carboxypeptidase B2</recommendedName>
<alternativeNames>Carboxypeptidase U-CPU, Plasma carboxypeptidase B-pCPB,...</alternativeNames>
```

Can you help me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: As for me, one XmlTransform could solve your task.

Comment: I tried to use the TransformXml, however I've been problem XSL because of  xmlns="http://uniprot.org/uniprot" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" in the xml. How can resolve this in the XSL: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

Comment: The error is in the line of xml:  xmlns="http://uniprot.org/uniprot"  and xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

How can I treat this in the XSLT?

Comment: that's not an error. can't understand your problem. maybe try to show xslt in question.

Comment: I think your solution is fine. I didn't  implement your solution because of entry tag that contains  xmlns="uniprot.org/uniprot" and xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance". I will try to resolve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you may use processor execute groovy script and parse xml with a script to get your values and put them into attributes.